# Disable collision dynamics from a spacific axis?

Tags: animation, physics

I honestly don't think there is a way to do this, but I am curious. Is there anyway within the collision physics to allow one specific axis to be animated while the other 2 are not animated and dynamic? What I mean is, say I wanted to animate an object to move on a specific path on the X-Axis, but I still want the Y and the Z axis to change according to the physics simulations. Any ideas?

Comment: the answer below is incorrect method as the constraints are visual only and the physics simulation will not take them into account